# How can I improve this question about rendering a star field in iOS?

Tags: discussion

I posted "[How to render an accurate AR star field in iOS with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945496/how-to-render-an-accurate-ar-star-field-in-ios-with-swift)" this morning and it immediately received a down vote and several close votes, and no comments or answers.

I know nothing about the specific domain of the question (OpenGL and 3D rendering in general) and my goal in asking was to get pointed in the right direction. I searched extensively before asking but was unable to find help. In fact the top Google result right now for "render a star field in iOS" is my question, and the rest of the results are not really relevant.

I *think* the question is valid, so obviously there's something wrong with the way I asked it. I'd like to improve it to get an answer for myself and also to make it searchable and useful for anyone else wondering how to do it. What can I do to improve my question?

Comment: You described a task, you did not ask an answerable question.  "Is there a "best" structure/technique" makes it hopelessly broad *and* subjective *and* very unlikely to give you the answer you actually need to get somewhere.  Instead explain what **specific** detail you got stuck on when trying to write the code.  Show that code, whatever it looks like.

Comment: (Off-topic: thanks for [this edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/348135/revisions) - was that a split infinitive? I do a lot of editing so would like to be able to spot this stuff, especially if it is me that writes it!).

Answer (score 4):

I like your question (and would like to see the answer), but it is extremely broad I'm afraid, as the correct answer could make up a book (if there's no existing framework, which there may not be).

This type of "point me in the right direction" question is no longer well received on SO because it's one of its most abused categories ("Halp plz I want to build Facebook clone").

The only way to make it work, I think, is to break it down in its separate tasks and pursue those until you hit a roadblock, and then ask about *that*.

I'd research the "AR + iOS" field ([ARToolkit for iOS looks nice](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=5_iOS:ios_about)) and see whether they have either examples, or specialized community resources that may be more tolerant of broad questions.